# Webform Civicrm Custom Fields across Multiple Contacts not working in Drupal 7 and Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, webform-civicrm, drupal-8, drupal-7

I created a custom fieldset in CiviCRM, with the following field types,

- File Field
- Two Date Fields
- Two Country Fields

With a "Tab with table" style

A webform with CiviCRM Integration and multiple contacts were created and the custom fields on contact 2, contact 3, etc were enabled.

I created a webform submission. The custom fields on contact 2,3+ aren't added to CiviCRM, only on Contact 1.  Please help, I have a very important system that I'm working on for an immigration assistance NPO, and would appreciate help on what might be causing this

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re -> Tab with Table style are these Multi value custom fields? We recently fixed a bug re: such custom fields in WFC D8/D9 and backported it to D7. What versions are you using? Are you able to clone from git or pull in a patch?

PS Multi value custom fields do complicate things (like eg reporting) so it may be a better option to create a regular Custom data set with the fields you need in it.

For sure non-Multi value custom fields across multiple contacts are working well - we're collecting custom fields data for up to 5 Contacts in e.g. a Family Registration form (up to 2 Adults + up to 3 Kids) - we did this in D7 -> and now on D8 (this project just upgraded).

Comment: Craig, if it has not already been considered, sometimes multi-record fields can be replaced with Activities.

Comment: I’m considering doing this but, I haven’t fully grasped it yet, you mind giving some pointers